# Why is react removing my class names?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I'm learning Reactjs, and I am rendering a simple page with some components.
One of this components is this:

```
class Header extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return  (
            <header>
                <div class="container">
                    <Logo />
                    <Navigation />
                </div>
            </header>
        );
    }
}

export default Header
```

I'm using **Bootstrap CSS** I want the `div` inside the header to use the styles of `container`, how ever, after build, the class is gone.

Is there a way to force the attribute class in the components?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to use the `className` attribute instead of the `class` attribute, e.g :

```
class Header extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return  (
            <header>
                <div className="container">
                    <Logo />
                    <Navigation />
                </div>
            </header>
        );
    }
}
```

Check the list of **[Supported Attributes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html#supported-attributes)** in the documentation.

> All attributes are camel-cased and the attributes `class` and `for` are `className` and `htmlFor`, respectively, to match the DOM API specification.