# bootstrap is not working in ReactJS code

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I want to use Bootstrap for creating a table in ReactJS. I have written the code bellow and have used `class="container"` in `<div>` and `class="table table-striped"` in `<table>` but the bootstrap is not working in this code. Please tell what can be the issue?

**app.js**

```
render : function() {
        return (
            <div class="container">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <tbody>
                    {this.state.rows.map((r) => (
                        <tr>
                            <td>{r}</td>
                            <td>
                                <button onClick={() => this.deleteRow(r)}>Delete</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <input trype="text" id={"newVal"} onChange={this.updateNewValue}></input>
                <button id="addBtn" onClick={this.addRow}>ADD</button>
            </div>
        );
    },
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sample Project</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.4/flatly/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="app.js" type="text/babel"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="display"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please check the console in your browser when you see unexpected behaviour. There should be a message there telling you exactly what's wrong here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is react removing my class names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35103683/why-is-react-removing-my-class-names)

Answer (score 8):

Import Bootstrap CSS and optionally Bootstrap theme CSS at the beginning of your src/index.js file:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

Answer (score 2):

In `jsx` you should use the `className` key word instead of `class`.
For example:
`<table className="table table-striped">`

You can read about it in the [DOCS](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#classname).

Answer (score 1):

To specify a CSS class, use the className attribute. This applies to all regular DOM and SVG elements like `<div>, <a>,` and others.

If you use React with Web Components (which is uncommon), use the class attribute instead.

Answer (score 1):

By default `npm install` will install latest version of bootstrap that is version 5.
here we need to enable version 4 in order to work and here is the list of steps to follow.

1. to uninstall bootstrap 5
   `npm uninstall bootstrap`
2. Install any bootstrap version 4 series.
   `npm install bootstrap@4.6.0`

Now import Bootstrap CSS in your src/index.js file:

`import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue in 2022.Simply uninstalling bootstrap library and installing lower version like 4.x.x works for me.